# Using a.append to create a numpy array of a desired shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I am trying to `append` data from 31 files in a directory into a `numpy` array using the code below.

```
directory = r"C:\Users\matth\Downloads\AMSRE"
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for f in filenames:
        if f.startswith("AMSR_E_L3_DailyLand_V06_201001"):
            log = open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r')
            file_name = (("C:\\Users\\matth\\Downloads\\AMSRE\\") + f)
            hdf = SD(file_name, SDC.READ)
            g = gdal.Open(('HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:') + file_name + (':Ascending_Land_Grid:A_Soil_Moisture'))
            sm = g.ReadAsArray()
            lons = np.fromstring ( urllib2.urlopen("ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/tools/easegrid/lowres_latlon/MLLONLSB").read(), \
dtype=np.int32 )/100000.
            lats = np.fromstring ( urllib2.urlopen("ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/tools/easegrid/lowres_latlon/MLLATLSB").read(), \
dtype=np.int32 )/100000.
            lons = lons.reshape(sm.shape)
            lats = lats.reshape(sm.shape)
            smm = np.ma.array ( sm, mask=np.logical_or ( sm==-9999, sm==9999))
            soil_moisture = []
            soil_moisture.append(smm)
            soil_moisture2006 = np.asarray(soil_moisture)
        output = np.vstack(soil_moisture2006)
```

The files all start with `AMSR_E_L3_DailyLand_V06_201001`, which is why I have the line

```
if f.startswith("AMSR_E_L3_DailyLand_V06_201001"):
```

One file has a shape of `(586, 1383)`. I would like to have a `numpy` array with a shape of `(31, 586, 1383)`, as there are 31 files in the directory. However, when I `print` the `shape` of the `output` array I have made in my code, its shape is `(586, 1383)`, and I have no idea why. Does anyone know how I can use `append` to create a numpy array with a shape of `(31, 586, 1383)`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Initialize `soil_moisture` outside loop.  And also turn it into an array after the loop.  You shouldn't need the `vstack`.  Have you practiced doing this with small interactive cases?  Start small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.vstack` does indeed stack an array (or tuple) of numpy arrays into the rows of an array, but it seems like you're giving it a single array.

I'd recommend initializing `output` the empty array (or some other falsey value) before you loop through your data. I'd then recommend replacing the last line with the following, keeping the indentation from what it was previously

```
if output:
    output = np.vstack((output,soil_moisture2006))
else:
    output = soil_moisture2006
```

This will attempt to append the data to `output`, unless it's the first set of data, in which case it will initialize `output` to that data. This ensures that `output` is the same shape as the rest of your data, so you can use `vstack` on it. Like the comment mentioned, I don't really know if you need to use `vstack`, but it seems easier to me to try to answer your question using the methods you've used than to rewrite it entirely.

I don't have your files, so obviously I can't run this to test it, but it seems like it might resolve your problem. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Oldtimers discourage the use of array concatenate (or any of the `stack` variants) in a loop.  List append is more efficient.